# How to remove 'internet explorer block this website from displaying content with security certificate errors' while running selenium scripts in IE10

Tags: selenium, junit, webdriver, internet-explorer-10

I am running scripts in IE10, requirement is to view a document, but its blocked due to security question 'Internet Explorer blocked this website from displaying content with security setting errors'

I want to get rid of this message, anybody have any ides on this

Comment: Can yo provide a screenshot of the error?

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure, but try to add the website in the 'trusted sites'. (Internet Options --> Security --> Trusted Sites --> click sites button)

Then change 'trusted zone' settings to allow website to run scripts. But be cautious to add only the sites you trust.(Internet Options --> Security --> Trusted Sites --> click Custom Level)

Answer (score 0):

I would get to the bottom of why there is a security exception to begin with.  But if you just want to ignore all security issues regardless, this might help.

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
caps.setCapability(
    InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
    true);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
driver.get("http://seleniumhq.org");
driver.quit();
```

Read more from http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html